# Excel macro for pivot table creation runs fine on Windows, not on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, pivot-table

I have a macro that runs great in Win but not a Mac.

Error on mac is:

> "Run time error '5'; Invalid procedure call or argument"

Statement flagged on Mac (the 1st and 2nd physical lines below are actually on 1 line, as are 3rd and 4th, so no need for underscore):

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, 
SourceData:=Selection.CurrentRegion.Address, Version:=6). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="", TableName:="PivotTable1", 
    DefaultVersion:=6
```

Is there anything in that statement not supported on the Mac?

Windows environment:

- OS: Win 7 Professional
- Excel:  MS Office 365 ProPlus, version 1708

Mac environment:

- MacOS: version 10.13.3
- Excel: 15.33

I can post the entire macro if necessary.  Thought I'd start with just seeing if some obvious function/object isn't supported on the MacOS version of Excel.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure Version 6 is valid for Mac? What happens if you try version 5 instead?

Comment: Thanks - we tried but that didn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

This error can be caused by not having the proper references enabled/disabled in your project.

Go into the Visual Basic portion, click Tools (top left of the window) and then click References. Remove all `MISSING:` references and re-run.

Note: I'm still pretty new to VBA, this has been how I've fixed the exact same error along with what I've found from a quick search of the error

Comment: Thanks - we will check the References section and report back.

Comment: Something to note- The references can be added automatically whenever the project is opened. If you're opening the project on a Mac and the same project on a PC, any saving may change the references (have seen this with trying to use Office '07 Access and Office 2016 Access)